# Плагин PopUp окно wordpress

Tags: wordpress, popup

Кто - нибудь знает , какой плагин можно поставить на wordpress , мне нужно вывод popup окна при нажатии на ссылку.

Comment: любой плагин, вон тот же magnific-popup, неплохо работает

Comment: Этих плагинов тьма. Поищите в официальном репозитории. Я довольно долго использовал Easy Fancy Box

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что поиск библиотек, плагинов оффтопик для сайта.

Comment: @AK данный вопрос имеет характер общего значения и основывается на опыте других пользоваетелей, которые уже сталкивались с данной проблемой.

Comment: Подобного рода вопросы - оффтопик для сайта, посмотрите обсуждения на мете ([например это](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2615/213987)).

Answer (score 1):

Если шаблон свой, то добавь класс на ссылку и воспользуйся моим скриптом.

```
    Lorem ipsum <a class="call_popup">link to</a> popup window
<div class="popup">
  <div class="popup_header"><i>x</i></div>
  <h3>content</h3>
</div>

    .call_popup {
  color: red;
}
.popup {
  display:none;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  padding: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0 0px 200px 0 rgba(32,19,45,0.90);
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50%-125px);
  left: calc(50%-125px);
}
.popup.open {
  display: block;
}
.popup_header {
  position: relative;
}
.popup_header i {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
}




 $('.call_popup').click(function(){
  $('.popup').toggleClass('open');
});
$('.popup_header i').click(function(){
  $('.popup').removeClass('open');
})
```

[codepen.io](https://codepen.io/vmoshikov/full/KxMLWe)

Comment: @Владислав_Мошиков я правильно понимаю что это jQuery?

Comment: @Владислав_Мошиков  спасибо огромное! Вроде работает как мне и надо , буду внедрять на сайт , скажите пожалуйста как можно скрыть PopUp окно при нажатии на пустой экран